# Can Sonar pass system properties into FindBugs? (e.g. findbugs.assertionmethods)

Tags: java, sonarqube, findbugs

FindBugs offers some [Analysis Properties](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/analysisprops.html) that are essentially Java system properties. Is there any way to pass such properties into FindBugs when it is launched by Sonar?

In the Sonar configuration for FindBugs there is no such option, only input fields for Exclude Filters, Timeout and Effort. I can find no general option for passing System properties or JVM parameters into analysis tools used bz Sonar.

What I want to achieve is passing the `findbugs.assertionmethods` parameter into FindBugs in order to prevent certain false positives happening due to static assertion helper classes we created.

Help and ideas are very much appreciated!

Comment: I think this is a valid feature request. I have created a JIRA issue: https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARJAVA-330 Feel free to vote for it.